# How to return all items in struct of byte32

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

I have a simple contract that allows me to list items and then return all the items listed but am having trouble  with return all the listed item..

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract ItemPlace{

     struct Item {
        bytes32 id;
        string name;
        uint256 price;
        bool isSold;
        address payable seller;
        address payable buyer;
    }
    mapping(bytes32 => Item) public items;
    mapping(bytes32 => bool) public itemAvailable;
    uint256 public itemIndex;

    function generateId(address to, uint256  count) internal  view returns(bytes32){
        return keccak256(abi.encode(address(this), to, count));
    }
    
    function listItem(string memory _name, uint256 _price) public {
        require(bytes(_name).length > 0, "Item name cannot be empty");
        require(_price > 0, "Item price must be greater than 0");
        bytes32 itemId = generateId(msg.sender, itemIndex);

        Item memory newItem = Item(itemId,_name, _price,false,payable(msg.sender),payable(address(0)) );
        items[itemId] = newItem;
        emit ItemListed(generateId(msg.sender, itemIndex), _name, _price, payable(msg.sender));
        itemIndex++;
    }

    function getAllItems() external  view returns (Item[] memory) {
        uint256 itemCount = 0;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < bytes32(uint256(0) - 1); i++) {
            if (itemAvailable[bytes32(i)]) {
                itemCount++;
            }
        }
        Item[] memory itemList = new Item[](itemCount);
        uint256 j = 0;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < bytes32(uint256(0) - 1); i++) {
            if (itemAvailable[bytes32(i)]) {
                itemList[j] = items[bytes32(i)];
                j++;
            }
        }
        return itemList;
    }


}
```

the problem is with the getAllItems() function ... there is a syntax error on the definition of the for loop

```
TypeError: Operator < not compatible with types uint256 and bytes32
  --> contracts/id.sol:71:29:
   |
71 |         for (uint256 i = 0; i < bytes32(uint256(0) - 1); i++) {
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

am asking if there is a possible solution for me to return all items .. it can be a correction of the current function or suggest a new function that will help me return the items

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're comparing uint256 with bytes32 in the getAllItems() function. To fix it, use itemIndex to iterate through items and return only available items. I'm not sure why you're trying to compare it uint_max, but here is a simple solution:

1. Create a new array `itemList` with the size of `itemIndex`.
2. Loop through items using itemIndex.
3. If an item is available, add it to itemList.
4. Return itemList.

Here is the code:

```
function getAllItems() external view returns (Item[] memory) {
    Item[] memory itemList = new Item[](itemIndex);
    uint256 j = 0;
    for (uint256 i; i < itemIndex; i++) {
        bytes32 itemId = bytes32(i);
        if (itemAvailable[itemId]) {
            itemList[j] = items[itemId];
            j++;
        }
    }
    Item[] memory filteredItemList = new Item[](j);
    for (uint256 i; i < j; i++) {
        filteredItemList[i] = itemList[i];
    }
    return filteredItemList;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i got a better solution